# Takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given)

Tags: python, class, arguments, self

i'm refactoring code in order to add object orientation and am just testing the code.

```
pattern = r"((([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5])[ (\[]?(\.|dot)[ )\]]?){3}([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]))"

class Lineobject(object):

        def __init__(self, pattern, line):
            self.ip = self.getip(self, pattern, line)

        def getip (self, pattern, line):
                for match in re.findall(pattern, line):
                    results = ''
                    ips = match[0]
                    usergeneratedblacklist.write(ips)
                    usergeneratedblacklist.write('\n')
                    return ips
```

When instantiating the class below I am getting an odd error. That of getip() takes exactly 3 arguments (4 given) which i do not know how to resolve.

```
for theline in f:

    if "Failed password" in theline:

        lineclass = Lineobject(pattern, theline)

    else:
        pass
```

Comment: `self` is passed implicitly when you call an instance method on an instance - that should be `self.ip = self.getip(pattern, line)`

Answer (score 10):

You are giving `self.getip()` four arguments because Python automatically adds in first `self` argument for bound methods. The expression:

```
self.getip(self, pattern, line)
```

results in:

```
getip(self, self, pattern, line)
```

which is *four* arguments.

Don't pass in `self` again:

```
self.ip = self.getip(pattern, line)
```

The very act of looking up the method on the instance (via `self.getip`) *binds* the method to handle that first argument for you.

Answer (score 2):

When calling an instance method, you don't pass the instance explicitly

ie.

```
self.ip = self.getip(pattern, line)
```